# how to create daily ts object?

Tags: r, time-series

I try to convert a daily dataset to ts from 2013-07-01 to 2014-08-31. What value should I set the frequency equal to?

```
ts(data,start=c(2013,7,1),frequency=7)?
```

Comment: There is also an `end` argument if you check `?ts`

Comment: Your `start` argument is incorrect.

Comment: ts(data,start=c(2013,7,1),end=c(2014,8,1),frequency=7)?

Comment: @CCIEGZM According to `?ts`, `start: the time of the first observation.  Either a single number or
          a vector of two integers...`

Comment: ts(data,start=c(2013,7),end=c(2014,8),frequency=7)?

Answer (score 0):

Below answer would be    helpful `ts(data,start=c(2013,1),end=c(2014,8),frequency=12*30)`